# Auto-vectorization with SSE2 movemask for bytes to bitmap with gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, sse, simd, auto-vectorization

With properly constructed C/C++ code one can hint gcc to generate efficient SIMD assembler on its own, without use of intrinsics, e.g. https://locklessinc.com/articles/vectorize/

I am trying to achieve a similar effect for movemask operation ([PMOVMSKB](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmovmskb) / *_movemask_epi8 family), but so far without success.

The simplest code I could think of:

```
#include <cstdint>

alignas(128) int8_t arr[32];

uint32_t foo()
{
    uint32_t rv = 0;

    for (int it = 0; it < 32; ++it)
    {
        rv |= (arr[it] < 0) << it;
    }

    return rv;
}
```

leads to assembly that fails to utilize move mask instruction: https://godbolt.org/z/3XimYc

**Does anyone have an idea if there's a way to do that with gcc without explicitly using intrinsics?**

I haven't looked into MD files and associated implementation in gcc yet (https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/gcc/config/i386).

Comment: I had no luck with gcc or clang extracting the MSB with an unsigned right-shift instead of a compare, either.  https://godbolt.org/z/DuVdF5.  Or reducing the count to 16, so it only had to find the XMM version. Also, some of the code gen is pretty horrible and clunky for gcc and clang.  Unpacking to 32-bit integers for variable-count shifts makes sense if they miss `pmovmskb`, but it's a mess.

Comment: I'm not really sure what your goal is here. If you explicitly want to get a movemask instruction, use the intrinsic. If you have non-artificial code which could benefit from using movemask make a feature-request to the compiler-maintainers.

Comment: @chtz The OP has a very legitimate use-case here and one which many people benefit from. Oftentimes, I've found avoiding intrinsics and coaxing auto-vectorization to result in better generated code with many desirable characteristics such as good code generation across different architectures and making the best utilization of the specified `-march`. It's also forwards thinking as your code will be able to better benefit from future improvements to GCC and to new instructions added to CPUs.