# x86 Performance difference between Shift and Add when packing bits?

Tags: c, performance, x86, cpu-architecture

Originally I was benchmarking some C code that looked something like:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NANOSEC_PER_SEC 1000000000LL

static inline void PackInt8Shifts(const int8_t* values, volatile uint8_t* out) {
  *out = (values[0] | values[1] << 1 | values[2] << 2 | values[3] << 3 | values[4] << 4 |
          values[5] << 5 | values[6] << 6 | values[7] << 7);
}

static inline void PackInt8NoShifts(const int8_t* values, volatile uint8_t* out) {
  *out = (values[0] | ((values[1] + 0x1) & 0x2) | ((values[2] + 0x3) & 0x4) |
          ((values[3] + 0x7) & 0x8) | ((values[4] + 0xf) & 0x10) |
          ((values[5] + 0x1f) & 0x20) | ((values[6] + 0x3f) & 0x40) |
          ((values[7] + 0x7f) & 0x80));
}


int main(void) {
  const size_t niters = 100000000;
  const int8_t values[8] = {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1};
  volatile uint8_t out;
  struct timespec start, end;
  
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < niters; i++) {
    PackInt8Shifts(values, &out);
  }
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);
  printf("ns duration of PackInt8Shifts was: %lld\n",
         (end.tv_sec * NANOSEC_PER_SEC + end.tv_nsec)
         - (start.tv_sec * NANOSEC_PER_SEC + start.tv_nsec));

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < niters; i++) {
    PackInt8NoShifts(values, &out);
  }
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);
  printf("ns duration of PackInt8NoShifts was: %lld\n",
         (end.tv_sec * NANOSEC_PER_SEC + end.tv_nsec)
         - (start.tv_sec * NANOSEC_PER_SEC + start.tv_nsec));

  return 0;
}
```

After compilation, a few invocations of this consistently show the non-shifting function as out-performing the shifting function:

```bash
$ gcc -O3 packint.c 
$ ./a.out
ns duration of PackInt8Shifts was: 17310031
ns duration of PackInt8NoShifts was: 11727328
$ ./a.out
ns duration of PackInt8Shifts was: 16955954
ns duration of PackInt8NoShifts was: 11287199
$ ./a.out
ns duration of PackInt8Shifts was: 17187124
ns duration of PackInt8NoShifts was: 11239957
```

[When inspecting the output of godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYgATKVpMGoAPrnkpJfWQE8Ayo3QBhVLQCuLBiADMAdlInABk8BkwAOU8AI0xiEABWUgAHVAVCewZXDy9fAJS0uwEQsMiWGLjE60xbDKECJmICLM9vfytMG0KGOoaCYojo2ISresbmnLaFUb7QgbKh%2BIBKK1R3YmR2DgBSPR9Q5A8sAGotn2cp/FQAOgRT7C2NAEEdvYYD92PT51CCAgBPJKYBQ3O4PZ67faHTAnM52Nggnz3J5gl5YGhhI7hR7hADyQmwzlMymwACVTPjnEcuBoabTaUEgiinlMmHZkEdQrRZkcAG6oPDoI7KJjIADWAElBAAOIQIPBUAgKCBoBhTDnS0wEABUvLE7iBpF5blZdGh7h%2BUs1OtWBEWJz8ACEwUcjlqbTCACJHCA8vVArbxB0aANerZ%2BSm%2Bjz%2BwNcEMw5xfKn2iN%2BhQBh16ONfRN6ZO6qNpwM%2BLNnRM%2BPOR/WFh2SEsJs5HSTJ50u1ttyvRh3xOuJ%2BIV1PpgBsPYbg/7BfTfhHlL8i1OTuRfg9TMeLLZ6q5GL5AqFIol0vCqFl8sVyoEaotVvzVcNfKMdnoR3NGu1RxtdrDC8eLrd7gInu9Dtq2DeJQ3Db0fQHGMsz0B0jg0VQuA/PQxwQvQP3AqAgPTTNQJOWD4NUHxkNQ1RJAwhMnjbaiIOwosYLghDZ3w0ipQo2ioJrBjCKoEjCOpCiWxol0sM47s8J2RjEN4ljCL0DR2NEidA2HCSCIQnwZJ2UjJAU5sqOEkTIOUh0pzUqS/C0lDCKlBS5x8L8w2XZEXMeH4jhYJhQh9fl0Awr8XRVNU0gAL0wTUjgYQhYgUADqTpWl5xbIL/0vf86IdKUSzAh0uENPL4Pyw0NGKoqqScpKDLvE1H2fAhLX/G1Ku/I4pmIdxbCOOEgUBdkWUaQ0nGal1ktoVAxVMYBMF%2BPA2AgZwghxZwAGlTBJbBHiCAAVcUAFlsENbT%2BttYajn4YhvVC8LUoA4MHI5eNIui4g03uvBJMk/yhN3MVJXq48FSVIDDpQ99ToqgyDnG0VJum7r5sWla1o27a9oOlinHsgKjiSYgfioCAdj0VUjnQNYTQEN8qB%2B/d/rlQGjgAdyYBQQHw%2BJaFodAA2cBgidIb7qIgJwrgIHlTCUdkdSxXEKSJUlyQJfC4JFsXTFVao5wM4SAFpLumUXxcl11MWxPECXlskKWV1qDbVjXkEWLGV0CsaJqmma5oWpbVvWzadv2kHB2O52DPOy68DCiK8Fu%2BcHsTKKCBiuP3tgz77Wxl1hV%2Bg8j3p09gZYsGHJbCGWqh924dmzAEZ95H/bRoPMdO3H8cJvRidisniAphgqZpv6pUPAHFSZlm2Z2DmuZ5vmO4F7WaOFhh0ENiXqhNmXzcJYkraVySjlV8WHa1lrdf13pV%2BN6WzblnfFcpffjtX4/Q%2BeAziGmtY%2B7uxylzBDhli0E4PEXg3gOBaFIKgTglIFCrHWNCF4eheAEE0AA5YooEglSARwSQoDUGQM4LwVmeUUHgIAaQOAsAkBoBYEkU0ZAKBnlofQlAwAuA%2BAMDQWgScXqUCiPgqIoQGh/E4DwUggjmDED%2BDiKI2hqikLETQtgggcQMFoCIshpAsBRHcMAZwYhaCs24LwLAnkTDiE0fgD%2BNQeRAnwZgVQ1Q/ybDET8Do%2BCuRRB7lI1wWB8EEDxiwUR5CqBGGAAoAAangTAjMcSAjAWI/gggRBiHYFIGQghFAqHUJo3QeUjAmBAOYUwlhPGs0gMsVASQuhGN4KgWxxA8ZYHKRAZYVQagOCXi4NwLQJCJGCLMUo5QEiJHyOkAQ4xvBcFGakcZDB%2BhDIWJUDo8jajTEmX09onQ1m9AWYMColR1k9JyNMkYuzBn7JGW0uBGx9CAOAXgzRUCOBHFUFKQcOtBxNmAMgdk7Cri5ggLgQgJB8IcMWMg1BTtSAIEwEwLAcRWmkAwfELBnBcGkDARA55RCQAlVIVoaF2CkGYvwTi0gBK0GkAaWkBwkggA%3D%3D) I noticed a shifting expression like `| values[2] << 2` would generate code equivalent to:

```
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        add     rax, 2
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rax]
        sal     eax, 2
        or      edx, eax
```

for any non-zero index, whereas the equivalent expression `| ((values[2] + 0x3) & 0x4)` not using shifts yields:

```
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        add     rax, 2
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rax]
        add     eax, 3
        and     eax, 4
        or      edx, eax
```

Is it really the single `sal` versus two `add` instructions that is causing the performance regression? When I look through [Agner Fog's instruction tables](https://www.agner.org/optimize/) (volume 4) I see

| Instruction | Operands | Ops | Latency | Reciprocal Throughput |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ADD, SUB | r,i | 1 | 1 | 0.25 |
| SHL, SHR, SAR | r,i/CL | 1 | 1 | .5 |

Which if I understand correctly means I should on average expect no real difference between the single shift and 2 add instructions?

Comment: Is it  because your cpu has more adder pipelines than shifting pipelines maybe? Also you are packing compile-time constant bits. Is it same with runtime too?

Comment: Apparently you're looking at performance for an AMD Excavator CPU, based on the rows from the table you quoted.  Intel CPUs also have 2/clock shift throughput for immediate shifts, but worse for shift-by-CL.  (Because of FLAGS handling; prefer BMI2 no-flags shifts especially when tuning for Intel).  Do you have an old Excavator CPU?  Previous Bulldozer-family had weak integer cores without many ALU execution ports, but those can apparently run 4/clock add.  But it's still Bulldozer-family so there are probably lost of bottlenecks...

Comment: Yea runtime with varying bits exhibits the same issue. The CPU is a 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1255U

Comment: You have an Intel CPU?  Different CPUs have different microarchitectures; that's kind of the whole point of Agner's tables having sections for each different one.  You have an Alder Lake with 2 P-cores and 8 E-cores. Probably the OS ran your process on a P-core every time, or an E-core.  https://uops.info/ has good data on them (with info on the microbenchmark experiments that gave the data behind every number in their tables).  See also https://uica.uops.info/ for a good loop analyzer that models the front-end and back-end pretty well.

Comment: It looks like you didn't do any warm-up runs to make sure the CPU got to max turbo before your timed region.  17 milliseconds isn't very long. [Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987)

Comment: I'd expect overall front-end uop throughput might be more of a bottleneck than back-end shift port throughput (also 2/clock on Alder Lake P-cores vs. 5/clock for `add r32, i8`).  In which case the one with fewer total instructions would be faster.

Comment: @PeterCordes ah thanks for the feedback. You made me realize that I was looking at the wrong sheet in the excel file download. The Intel Pentium sheet still shows the same number of clock cycles for register/immediate operands, but maybe the difference is ADD has uv pairability whereas SAL only has u pairability

Comment: On the topic of warmup that could also be true, but I actually came to find this performance bottleneck working at a much higher level running Python benchmarks https://github.com/apache/arrow-nanoarrow/pull/280#issuecomment-1688662632 where the differences were even more pronounced

Comment: Intel P5 Pentium from 1993 (in-order dual-issue) is even more different from your Alder Lake than Excavator!!  As Agner says in his microarch PDF, he hasn't tested Alder Lake.  Maybe he didn't want to spend the effort since https://uops.info/ has made his spreadsheet mostly obsolete, while his microach PDF is still very useful and he sometimes spots things testing of single instructions in isolation won't catch.

Comment: Anyway, re: packing and unpacking bits: on a modern Intel you'd want to use `pext` and `pdep` if BMI2 is available.  (Or AMD Zen 3 and later; unfortunately it's available but slow on AMD Zen 2 and earlier.)  If BMI2 isn't fast, or you have more than 8 bools to do, SSE2 `pmovmskb` can pack 1 bit per byte into a scalar integer mask.  If you can't get a compiler to emit that from portable code, there's a multiply bithack: phuclv's answer on [How to create a byte out of 8 bool values (and vice versa)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8461126) shows that and the x86-specific tricks for pack/unpack.

Comment: Thank you @Peter Cordes for your impressive knowledge and guidance!

Comment: So for example the asm you want for `PackInt8` is `movq xmm0, [rdi]` / `pslld xmm0, 7` / `pmovmskb eax, xmm0` / `mov [rsi], al` / `ret`.  Getting GCC to emit that without intrinsics like `_mm_movemask_epi8` is an unsolved problem ([Auto-vectorization with SSE2 movemask for bytes to bitmap with gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54326264)).  IDK if it would help for the compiler to know the `int8_t` values were always `0` or `1`; otherwise it has to faithfully OR them together.  Not e.g. `lea reg, [reg + reg*2]` which is a shift-and-add, although maybe not useful with data from memory.

Comment: Interesting idea to add to different lengths of one-bits to do a different shift on each bool element.  That could be useful on AArch64 ASIMD / NEON before a horizontal-add instruction to pack bits, although I think AArch64 has byte granularity shifts (with per-element-variable counts), unlike x86.

Comment: Oh, I thought your asm looked weird, using `[rbp - 8]` like it was a frame pointer for unoptimized code.  That's because it is; you forgot to enable optimization in your Godbolt link.  With `-O3`, the store to `volatile uint8_t out` stays, but the computation of the value to be stored is gone after inlining: `mov   BYTE PTR [rsp+15], -53`.  Both your timed regions have the same contents: a loop around two mov-immediate stores.  So the performance effect is 100% a duplicate of [Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](//stackoverflow.com/q/60291987) - lack of warm-up, and work optimized out

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/G4nvY1eMq uses `asm( "" :: "g"(values) : "memory");` to tell the compiler the array contents might have changed.  (Along with making it non-`const`; `const` inputs are the opposite of what you want for microbenchmarking how fast *run-time* data processing can go.)  Anyway, asm looks reasonable; you could benchmark that against a multiply bithack.  (Might still want to bump up the repeat count by 10x.)

Comment: Apparently auto-vectorization of array-of-bool to bitmask is still an unsolved problem for LLVM, too.  https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/41997 -  at least for the test-case  [Clang: autovectorize conversion of bool\[64\] array to uint64\_t bit mask](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75030873)